# Fitting exponential and 5 gaussians to data in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, gaussian

I am trying fit an exponential function and 5 Gaussians to my data. What I am aiming for is something along these lines: (where gDNA Fit is the exponential; 1-5Nuc Fit are the 5 Gaussians; Total fit is the sum of all the fits)

[image]

The way I approached it was fitting the exponential and then based on that introduce a cut-off that would allow me to fit the gaussians without taking into consideration the already fitted data. (I have already cut the data at 100 as this is where it dips down to 0)

The problem is I don't seems to be able to fit the exponential properly and the gaussians are off the scale:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot

#Exponential

x = np.array([1.010000000000000000e+02,1.100000000000000000e+02,1.190000000000000000e+02,1.280000000000000000e+02,1.370000000000000000e+02,1.460000000000000000e+02,1.550000000000000000e+02,1.640000000000000000e+02,1.730000000000000000e+02,1.820000000000000000e+02,1.910000000000000000e+02,2.000000000000000000e+02,2.090000000000000000e+02,2.180000000000000000e+02,2.270000000000000000e+02,2.360000000000000000e+02,2.450000000000000000e+02,2.540000000000000000e+02,2.630000000000000000e+02,2.720000000000000000e+02,2.810000000000000000e+02,2.900000000000000000e+02,2.990000000000000000e+02,3.080000000000000000e+02,3.170000000000000000e+02,3.260000000000000000e+02,3.350000000000000000e+02,3.440000000000000000e+02,3.530000000000000000e+02,3.620000000000000000e+02,3.710000000000000000e+02,3.800000000000000000e+02,3.890000000000000000e+02,3.980000000000000000e+02,4.070000000000000000e+02,4.160000000000000000e+02,4.250000000000000000e+02,4.340000000000000000e+02,4.430000000000000000e+02,4.520000000000000000e+02,4.610000000000000000e+02,4.700000000000000000e+02,4.790000000000000000e+02,4.880000000000000000e+02,4.970000000000000000e+02,5.060000000000000000e+02,5.150000000000000000e+02,5.240000000000000000e+02,5.330000000000000000e+02,5.420000000000000000e+02,5.510000000000000000e+02,5.600000000000000000e+02,5.690000000000000000e+02,5.780000000000000000e+02,5.870000000000000000e+02,5.960000000000000000e+02,6.050000000000000000e+02,6.140000000000000000e+02,6.230000000000000000e+02,6.320000000000000000e+02,6.410000000000000000e+02,6.500000000000000000e+02,6.590000000000000000e+02,6.680000000000000000e+02,6.770000000000000000e+02,6.860000000000000000e+02,6.950000000000000000e+02,7.040000000000000000e+02,7.130000000000000000e+02,7.220000000000000000e+02,7.310000000000000000e+02,7.400000000000000000e+02,7.490000000000000000e+02,7.580000000000000000e+02,7.670000000000000000e+02,7.760000000000000000e+02,7.850000000000000000e+02,7.940000000000000000e+02,8.030000000000000000e+02,8.120000000000000000e+02,8.210000000000000000e+02,8.300000000000000000e+02,8.390000000000000000e+02,8.480000000000000000e+02,8.570000000000000000e+02,8.660000000000000000e+02,8.750000000000000000e+02,8.840000000000000000e+02,8.930000000000000000e+02,9.020000000000000000e+02,9.110000000000000000e+02,9.200000000000000000e+02,9.290000000000000000e+02,9.380000000000000000e+02,9.470000000000000000e+02,9.560000000000000000e+02,9.650000000000000000e+02,9.740000000000000000e+02,9.830000000000000000e+02,9.920000000000000000e+02])
y = np.array([3.579280000000000000e+05,3.172290000000000000e+05,1.759610000000000000e+05,1.352610000000000000e+05,1.069130000000000000e+05,9.721000000000000000e+04,9.908200000000000000e+04,1.168480000000000000e+05,1.266880000000000000e+05,1.264760000000000000e+05,1.279850000000000000e+05,1.198880000000000000e+05,1.117730000000000000e+05,1.005850000000000000e+05,9.038500000000000000e+04,7.532400000000000000e+04,6.235500000000000000e+04,5.249600000000000000e+04,4.445600000000000000e+04,3.808000000000000000e+04,3.612100000000000000e+04,3.460600000000000000e+04,3.209700000000000000e+04,3.008200000000000000e+04,3.090700000000000000e+04,3.208600000000000000e+04,2.949700000000000000e+04,3.111600000000000000e+04,3.125700000000000000e+04,3.152700000000000000e+04,3.198700000000000000e+04,3.373800000000000000e+04,3.171200000000000000e+04,3.124900000000000000e+04,3.109700000000000000e+04,3.002200000000000000e+04,2.720100000000000000e+04,2.413600000000000000e+04,1.873100000000000000e+04,1.768900000000000000e+04,1.510600000000000000e+04,1.358800000000000000e+04,1.354400000000000000e+04,1.198900000000000000e+04,1.182800000000000000e+04,6.926000000000000000e+03,1.230000000000000000e+04,3.734000000000000000e+03,6.631000000000000000e+03,7.085000000000000000e+03,7.151000000000000000e+03,7.195000000000000000e+03,7.265000000000000000e+03,6.966000000000000000e+03,6.823000000000000000e+03,6.357000000000000000e+03,5.977000000000000000e+03,5.464000000000000000e+03,4.941000000000000000e+03,4.543000000000000000e+03,3.992000000000000000e+03,3.593000000000000000e+03,3.156000000000000000e+03,2.955000000000000000e+03,2.740000000000000000e+03,2.701000000000000000e+03,2.528000000000000000e+03,2.481000000000000000e+03,2.527000000000000000e+03,2.476000000000000000e+03,2.456000000000000000e+03,2.461000000000000000e+03,2.420000000000000000e+03,2.346000000000000000e+03,2.326000000000000000e+03,2.278000000000000000e+03,2.108000000000000000e+03,1.893000000000000000e+03,1.771000000000000000e+03,1.654000000000000000e+03,1.547000000000000000e+03,1.389000000000000000e+03,1.325000000000000000e+03,1.130000000000000000e+03,1.057000000000000000e+03,9.460000000000000000e+02,9.790000000000000000e+02,8.990000000000000000e+02,8.460000000000000000e+02,8.360000000000000000e+02,8.040000000000000000e+02,8.330000000000000000e+02,7.690000000000000000e+02,7.020000000000000000e+02,7.360000000000000000e+02,6.390000000000000000e+02,6.690000000000000000e+02,6.770000000000000000e+02,6.100000000000000000e+02,5.700000000000000000e+02])

def func(x, a, c, d):
    return a*np.exp(-c*x)+d


#print np.exp(-x)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, y, p0=(1, 0.01, 1))

yy = func(x, *popt)

matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, y, 'ko')
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, yy)

#gaussian

from sklearn import mixture
import scipy

gmm = mixture.GMM(n_components=5, covariance_type='full')
gmm.fit(y)
pdfs = [p * scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, mu, sd) for mu, sd, p in zip(gmm.means_, (gmm.covars_)**2, gmm.weights_)]


density = np.sum(np.array(pdfs), axis=0)
#print density
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(x, density)

show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind to use least squares as opposed to maximum likelyhood I would suggest to fit the whole model at once, including the exponential with e.g. scipy curve_fit. You will never get a good fit to the exponential if you ignore the existance of the gaussian peaks. I recommend to use peak-o-mat (http://lorentz.sf.net) which is an interactive curve fitting software written in python. Within seconds you can get a result like this:

[image: multi peak fit example]

Comment: Can you please tell me what parameters you used?

Comment: The model in peak-o-mat's own 'language' is DEC GA1 GA2 GA3 GA4. You can pick an initial guess with the mouse by moving the components and fix them with left-click. Is that what you were asking for?

Comment: I can't figure out how you pick the initial guess with the mouse. Could you please tell me or better make a video which would show me? Thank you

Comment: Enter 'DEC GA1 GA2 GA3 GA4' as model by clicking on the corresponding buttons or by writing directly to the text box. Switch to the next tab, click 'Pick' (which means "make an initial guess by placing the components of the model on the plot") and move the pointer towards the plot. Click anyware near to where you expect the exponential decay to pass. Move the mouse and select a second point of the exponential. You are done with the exponential term now. Move the pointer towards the peak of one of the gaussian components, click to fix position and amplitude and move the pointer again to ...

Comment: ... specify the width of the gaussian distribution. Repeat the procedure for all components of the model. Once finished, the 'Fit' button turns active. Click and see what you get. Btw. the screenshot shows your data in semilog representation. This can be achieved by clicking on the corresponding icon of the small toolbar next to the plot area.